# How to generate a UID with only 7 characters and exclude repetition like imgur.com

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm

take a look at this URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIi3M.jpg

You will see that the URL has a seemingly random string generated, which is build from 7 characters of

1. small letters (26 characters)
2. big letters (26 characters)
3. numbers (10 numbers)

n =  (26+26+10) = 62

I would like to know how it is possible to generate a random string of only 7 characters, that works as a GUID.

With only 7 characters, imgur is using, they can generate 3.521.614.606.208 variations (62 to the power of 7). The question now arises, how imgur handles each variation to be used as an identifier, since it seems that those numbers are generated randomly.

Is there a way to find out, how it is possible to use 7 characters as UID and making sure, they don't repeat themselves?

One solution could be, to generate them in chunks and to use one after the other. Seems rather not good.

Any kind appreciated!

Btw. 
Random Strin best generated in PHP

Comment: Random string of 7 characters will not and can not work as `GUID`. `GUID` has its definition and its length is there for a reason obviously. What you can do is generate a random string. It won't, however, ever function as GUID.

Comment: Agree. Apparently even stackoverflow is using random/increasing numbers as unique identifier, even though they are not by definition a GUID: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one-liner to generate a random string:

```
substr(
    str_shuffle(
        str_repeat('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890', 7)
    ), 
    0, 
    7
)
```

Then, you can check in a database if it's already used or not like this for example:

```
while(
    existsInTheDB(
        $str = substr(
            str_shuffle(
                str_repeat(
                    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890',
                    7
                )
            ), 
            0, 
            7
        )
    )
){}

//now you can use $str
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume they have a database in the backend and handle the collisions. You generate an identifier, look if it still exists, then generate another one till you get one that doesn't exist.

Or they have just incremented some 64bit integer and generated a string from it.